# How can two tasks begin on the same day without a resource-conflict?

Tags: ms-project, tasks

In MS Project (current version), I have the following task setup and can't find a solution:

[image]

Short translation for columns:
Vorgangsname = Taskname
Arbeit = Work
Dauer = Duration
Anfang = Beginning
Ende = End

Not visible in the screenshot: Both tasks have the fixed day 2015-10-05 (Monday) and the resource-availability is 50% (global setting).

My question is: How can both tasks begin on the same day without a resource-conflict? My suggestion is, to change the percentage of the resource-availability per task, but I don't know where to find that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ResourceAvailability]

The problem here seems to be that the resource availability is only available at 50% - so if the resource works an 8 hr day, then he or she is only available for 4 hours of that day.  Increase this percentage to 100% if the resource is available for 1 full day.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the allocation of resources in units.

To do so:

1. In the windows menu open the second vue.
2. Select your tasks then on the bottom of the screen you see your resources, (click right and select "resources work" if you do not see the unit section).
3. Change the unit of your resources (like 50% on each task).

And done.

Comment: Please correct your description - there are spelling mistakes and I don't know what you mean with "windows menu".